# Change position of words

Tags: string, awk, replace, sed

I have file with multiples lines as given below with header for each species starting with '>'

```
>gi|398852808|ref|NZ_AKJD01000108.1| Pseudomonas sp. GM80 PMI37_contig126.126, whole genome shotgun sequence
CCGCAGGCTGCGATCTTTTGATGTTGTTTTTTTAAGATCAAGATCAAAAGATCGCAGCCTTCGGCAGCTCCTACAGGTGG
TCGTGGGTTTAAGCCGCTCAATCCAGTAAACTGCGGCACGTTTTTCTCTAAGTAGTGTTTTCCCCATGCAAATTGCTCTG
GCGCCCATGGAGGGGTTGGTCGACGACATCCTCCGCGACGTGCTGACCCGCGTTGGCGGCATCGATTGGTGCGTGACTGA
ATTCATTCGGGTCAACGATCAGTTGCTCACCCCGGCTTACTTCCACAAGTTCGGCCCCGAGCTGCTCAACGGTGCCCGCA
CGGCGTCCGGCGTGCCATTGCGTGTGCAATTGCTCGGTTCCGACCCGGTGTGCCTGGCGGAAAACGCTGCACTGGCCTGC
```

I would like to find the header and change it to

```
>NZ_AKJD01000108.1|kraken:taxid|398852808 Pseudomonas sp. A3(2016), complete genome
CGCGATGGTCGTTAACGAAAACGCATGCTTACTGGCTAAACGCGGCGCTCTTGACTCCAT
CGCGAGCAAGCTCGCTCCTACAGAAGAAAGCGGCGCTCTAGTGCGCCTCATCCCAGTTAT
TGCCTACCCCCACCTCGACCAGCAGCGGCACATCCAGTTGCGCGGCCCCGCTCATGTGCA
```

Without changing the structure of the file.

I tried this 
awk -v repl=">kraken:taxid|$ID|" '{ gsub(/^>/,repl,$0); print $0}' $FILE

I am able to move words but not able to remove or get the desired result.

Thanks

Comment: [edit] your question to explain the transformation you want to make. Right now your input and output look like 2 partially overlapping but otherwise unrelated blocks of text. For example, where did `A3(2016)` come from? Why did your output shrink by 2 lines? Why did `CCG...` become `CGC...`? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want to rearrange the fields on the header line:

```
 1  >gi
 2  398852808
 3  ref
 4  NZ_AKJD01000108.1
 5   Pseudomonas sp. GM80 PMI37_contig126.126, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

to be

```
 1  >NZ_AKJD01000108.1
 2  kraken:taxid
 3  398852808 Pseudomonas sp. A3(2016), complete genome
```

The awk you need is roughly this:

```
BEGIN { FS = "[|]" }

/^>/ {
     OFS = "|"

     split($5, words, / /)
     Pseudomonas = " " words[1] " " words[2] " " "A3(2016), complete genome"

     print ">" $4, "kraken:taxid", $2  Pseudomonas
     next
}

{ print }
```

My guess is that some of the output literals are actually lookups that categorize or rename the inputs. If so, you might want to construct associative arrays for them (from other input files) before processing the genome file.

HTH.